# Shell script to pull variable file1 and compare against variable in file2 and print difference

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I can't seem to get my head around this ... or I'm over analyzing this ....

Currently, I have a script that runs a query every 15mins, outputs to a tmp file, formats output with awk and then email results and stores a log file.

Tmp file sample data is ...

```
2014040800054265 D 08-Apr-2014 11:15 08-Apr-2014 00:00 OOS  
2014040800054267 E 08-Apr-2014 11:16 08-Apr-2014 00:00 OOS  
2014040800054279 D 08-Apr-2014 15:01 08-Apr-2014 00:00 OOS
```

Email file sample data is ...

```
Ticket #: 2014040800054265
Queue : D
Recieved Date : 08-Apr-2014
Recieved Time : 11:15
```

Basically, I want the script to only email new tickets ...

I have tried comparing with awk but it hasn't been working.

anyone have any suggestions please ?

your help is appreciated !

P.S Sorry for the bogus comments ...still getting used to this site : )

Comment: Can we have a sample of both files please?

Comment: thank you for responding ! the first column is the ticket number

Comment: 2014040800054265 D 08-Apr-2014 11:15 08-Apr-2014 00:00 OOS  
2014040800054267 E 08-Apr-2014 11:16 08-Apr-2014 00:00 OOS  
2014040800054279 D 08-Apr-2014 15:01 08-Apr-2014 00:00 OOS

Comment: @naab  2014040800054265 D 08-Apr-2014 11:15 08-Apr-2014 00:00 OOS    
    2014040800054267 E 08-Apr-2014 11:16 08-Apr-2014 00:00 OOS    
    2014040800054279 D 08-Apr-2014 15:01 08-Apr-2014 00:00 OOS

Comment: Seems like there's a lot of information in the question that has nothing to do with the question, and the necessary information is missing from the question. If I understand it, you just want to compare some specific fields in 2 files, right? Then simply post samples of the 2 input files plus the expected output. Get rid of all the pre-amble about how those input files are created as it's just distracting and will cause people not to bother wading through it all to try to understand what you want.

Comment: @Ed Morton  Thank you for the suggestion, after reviewing the post yeah it was a bit much ...sorry .. hope its better now

Comment: @naab Hello  I tried your suggestion however im getting a "for not matched" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe.

It parses the logfile to extract the tickets numbers only.

Then iterates over them and try a grep to found if it was sent.

```
LOGFILE="file1"
TMPFILE="file2"

for TICKET in $(awk '{print $1}' $LOGFILE); do
   if ! grep -q "Ticket #: ${TICKET} " $TMPFILE; then
      send_email_for_ticket $TICKET
   fi
done
```